# Deploy API REST IBM Hyperledger Composer Blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm developing a POC over IBM HyperLedger Blockchain. I have a business network developed and deployed in IBM Cloud. I can generate a working local API REST, but cannot make it work on cloud, on the deployed IP.
I'm following this guide:

https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/interacting/

You just have to execute the following command:

```
./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --business-network-card MY_BIZNET_CARD_NAME
```

But it doesn't deploy anything, and get the following (more related to kubernetes than blockchain).

```
Preparing yaml file for create composer-rest-server
Creating composer-rest-server pod
Running: kubectl create -f /Users/sm/jsblock/ibm-container-service/cs-offerings/scripts/../kube-configs/composer-rest-server.yaml
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
the server doesn't have a resource type "svc"
Creating composer-rest-server service
Running: kubectl create -f /Users/sm/jsblock/ibm-container-service/cs-offerings/scripts/../kube-configs/composer-rest-server-services-free.yaml
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
Composer rest server created successfully
```

Any ideas? Thanks too much.

Comment: That looks like your kube config is not correct and is trying to talk to a non existent kubenetes running on your local machine

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you have a correct kube config setup. Step 10 in https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/setup/ provides the details to set up KUBECONFIG as the error suggests that either it is not configured or not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks, you  was right. I completed the config proccess again and a new error appeared, but at least I've some movement...

Answer (score 0):

The document you refer to https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/interacting/ is being updated and should be available soon.

When you run the command `./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --business-network-card MY_BIZNET_CARD_NAME` - should be the name of the Network Admin for the network you deployed, NOT the PeerAdmin card so it will be something like `./create/create_composer-rest-server.sh --business-network-card admin@perishable-network`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing that. Specifying admin@tutorial-network (the sample admin card you create following the IBM/ Hyperledger Composer tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

Look like it's an issue of acceess control. You should make sure again you are running with Local Admin configuration.it will help you to run queries